# Node statistics past 24 hours

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I've got a 'Most Popular' block on my drupal website that uses the core 'Node Statistics: Views Today' filter in views.

I was hoping that it would filter by node views in the past 24 hours, but instead it clears statistics and starts from scratch once a day with cron run.

This means that everyday at 5pm (as that's when cron first ran), the block clears itself and shows 5 incredibly old stories, and then changes very rapidly for the next few minutes as stories begin to rack up view counts again.

Is there any way to filter by 24 hours instead of by day? Basically I am looking for this: http://drupal.org/project/node_extended_stats for Drupal 6, but there doesn't seem to be one.

Sorry if I'm being stupid. I've looked around and can't find anyone else asking this question, but I'm sure I'm not the only one with this problem.

Comment: the site is http://stand-news.co.uk by the way, though it's a pretty standard most popular block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the Statistics Pro module?

- http://drupal.org/project/statspro

Comment: Not sure how I missed that before. Thanks!